# not save the addresses accessed in browser history, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I need to configure a rails app in a way that it does not leave the browser to save the historic addresses accessed my app. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sounds really weird... Well, use iframes.

Comment: @user905731, why are you doing this? Do you need to worry about cookies, images, being able to do a text search and finding a different address with the content inside it?

Comment: Send everything as post?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There's no protocol, let alone one implemented by all popular browsers, that would allow such insecure behavior.

Users can choose things like Chrome's "Incognito Mode" or Safari's "Private Browsing" but you can't (and shouldn't be allowed to) force such a mode on the user.